# Translator app text is too small on ipad conversation screen

Tags: ipad, text, microsoft-translator

When using Microsoft Translator app on my ipad, the text is too small when using the conversation screen.

I tried changing a setting in ipad's ios settings app overall and for Translator. I also using the control panel pulldown to change text size. This worked for all areas of the Translator app except the conversation screen which still had the text too small.